# modifying jquery widget

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, widget

I'm using Eric Hynds' multiselect widget.

I'd like to modify it, adding an option and including an extra step in the _refresh method. Now I can modify the plugin easily enough to accomplish my aims, but what I'd like to do is to create a wrapper or similar that means I can update the widget in future, while keeping my changes separate.

The widget is built using jquery ui 1.8 widget factory .

What is the best way to achieve my aims?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing all your details, you can try extending the widget.

```
$.extend($.widget, {refresh:function(){your function here}});
```

I've used this for adding functionality to a widget, but not for overriding existing functions.

You also try using inheritance, which is probably the right call here. When defining your new widget there is an argument to pass in an existing base widget

```
(function ($) {
$.widget('an.originalwidget', $.a.yourwidget, {
    ...
    refresh: function() {
        // override code
    }
});
}(jQuery));
```

Here is a great link to try:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404085

Edit: I did this using Jquery 1.7.2, I notice you are using 1.8, while I don't think there will be any changes to this, you might want to check